# Query to data from two tables having same column but having different data

Tags: database, oracle

I have two tables one is Registration which has column as reg_id and first_name and other details
and the other table is activity which also has reg_id  ,first_name and other details with reg_id as common the tables. There can be multiple entries for 1 reg_id in activity table

I want to have query these two tables in such a way ,I want to know all those reg_id which have different first_name in both the tables.

Eg :if

```
1st table data
--------------                     
Reg_id   first_name                               
1        ashu
2        &parker
3        *fzz 
4        john


2nd Table data
--------------
Reg_id   first_name
1        ashu
2        parker
3        michel  
4        john
```

The output of my query should return 2,3 reg_ids

Comment: Your sample data is unreadable, can you tidy it up?

Answer (score 2):

```
select table1.reg_id from table1
inner join table2 on table1.reg_id = table2.reg_id
where table1.first_name <> table2.first_name
```

select the one reg id, joing the tables on  the reg id value.
where the two first name fields don't equal each other

SQL is not case sensitive either.

Answer (score 1):

Like this......

```
SELECT t1.reg_id 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.reg_id = t2.reg_id
WHERE t1.first_name <> t2.first_name
```

Here is a good link to help you understand SQL Joins : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp